# How to make a sky-to-ground view shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, photorealism

So, I have a scene with a cube which I have modified into a group of clouds and a plane which I intend to be the ground. The camera is placed such that I can see the ground through the scattered clouds.
Like so:

[image]

However, I'm not able to create the ground shader. I need it to look as realistic as possible.

Comment: Maybe use a photo?

Comment: @seaturtle I couldn't an HD image of it. If you can find any send a link my way.

Comment: Just google “earth from a plane” or similar : https://goo.gl/images/Uh6vj7

Comment: @RichSedman I tried using various HD images, the result wasn't satisfactory...I suppose images just don't cut it

Comment: Make the ground surface and with the cloud addon make cloud from the top view set the camera

Comment: @atek yes, I know.. the question is "How?" I already made the clouds, by the way

Comment: I would recommend the [Space VFX](http://www.creativeshrimp.com/spacevfx.html) tutorial, you can also find some free procedural planet tutorials like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dONehSMYEag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

By feeding a [wave texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/wave.html#wave-texture-node) into a [noise texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/noise.html#noise-texture-node),combined with [*true displacement*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/components/displacement.html#displacement), you can create a good starting point for a procedural terrain. The color ramp determines the shading, and the [RGB to BW node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/rgb_to_bw.html#rgb-to-bw-node) creates a grayscale mask from the color ramp for the parts that should be water.

Here is the node setup, this is based around the planet plane material from the [material library vx](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/materials/material_library.html#material-library) add-on which is now included in blender as of version 2.79:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The contents of the *displacement* node group:

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

The file to play with:

[image]

Comment: This works beautifully, but I have another question, is it possible to control the colors based on height? I have used the ANT landscape addon to create mountains, and I want the green part only on the "flat" surfaces. I tried to do this myself but was unsuccessful, some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of searching, the best search phrase is "NASA aerial view", you get many HD images without watermarks on them.

I used an image to do it this time, *although*, I am still interested in learning how to make a procedural shader for this.